# SQL how to force column to be unique if that row's foreign ID is the same?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, sql-update

In my schema, I have a table with

```
id | word | count | remote_id
-----------------------------
```

What I'd basically like to do so is that as I'm inserting rows into this table like:

```
insert into table (word, count, remote_id) VALUES ('cat', 10, 2);
```

Firstly, if 'cat' already exists with remote_id=2, I'd like the final value of count for 'cat' to be 10 + it's existing value.

If it's not present, it'll be inserted as usual.

How can I achieve this?

Also, right now I have an assertion that the column word must be unique, but I'd only like it unique per remote_id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you need the `id` column? If you can make the pair `word, remote_id` into the primary key  then you can user the [`on duplicate key` syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html)

```
insert into table (word, count, remote_id) VALUES ('cat', 10, 2)
on duplicate key update count = count +values(count);
```

Edit: I stand corrected.  You can use this syntax even without it being the primary key, as long as you have a unique index on the pair `word, remote_id`, which is what you want anyway to enforce that condition.

Answer (score 0):

In schema add  unique constrain to two columns

```
Alter table table_name add unique 'uni_undex'  (word, remote_id)
```

Edit:
For count 
You can write a trigger after insert event in plsql
Or select + ( update or insert)

Comment: Thanks but now how do I update my insert statements so that it updates the count value if it's already present for the remote_id?

Comment: The question is tagged mysql so not sure you can write anything in plsql - isn't that just Oracle?

Comment: Yeah no PL-SQL please. Thankfully that language is only contained to Oracle.